# how to update a single column of a table with the value from the select statement that gives the date difference?

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-update, sql-insert, datediff

I want to update a column of a table with the value coming from the following query.
SELECT DATEDIFF(days,'EndDate','StartDate') AS DiffDate. 
Can I do this in a single sql statement? Right now I have a table with columns(StartDate, EndDate, DiffDate) with values for StartDate and EndDate but not for DiffDate. DiffDate is null now. I am trying to update the value of DiffDate from null to the Date Difference.
I appreciate the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update TheNameOfYourTable
set DiffDate = DATEDIFF(days, EndDate, StartDate)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this query but the table I have has lots of records, and this query gives me error, it says the set value is not unique, may be it is because the DiffDate has more than one row. I have to update all the records with date difference which has start date and end date.

Comment: Please update your question with the table definition (Sql Server Management Studio -> Object Explorer -> right click on your table -> script table as => create to -> clipboard)

Comment: I was doing something like this, update.... set DiffDate =  select DATEDIFF(days, EndDate, StartDate). I just realize that I don't need to put select on the query. It works now. Thanks a ton.